# hitTestPoint breaking after local3DToGlobal call

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

SOLVED (I think, see edits)

hitTestPoint is giving me only false after the displayObject's parent calls local3DToGlobal.    I have the parent calling it because that's how I've found the coordinates are correct (don't know why, idea for that from http://actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=190115 )
Any ideas?

```
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.geom.Point;

var circle:Shape = new Shape();
circle.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
circle.graphics.drawCircle(40, 40, 40);

circle.z= 30;

addChild(circle);

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkIt);

function checkIt(e:Event){

trace(circle.hitTestPoint(40,40,true));


var pos3D= new Vector3D(circle.x,circle.y,circle.z);
var globalLoc;

//This line doesn't break hitTestPoint, but it doesn't give the correct
//global x,y projected coordinates of the circle
globalLoc=circle.local3DToGlobal(pos3D);
trace (globalLoc);


//This line breaks the hitTest but is the only way I can get the correct
//global x,y projected coordinates of the circle.
globalLoc=circle.parent.local3DToGlobal(pos3D)
trace (globalLoc);


trace(circle.hitTestPoint(40,40,true));
}

stop();
```

EDIT: Want to see something strange? I added a container for the circle.  Now do the check twice (hit any key twice): you get

true

false (just like last time)

---

true  (ok, better)

true  (weird)

---

true  (...)

true  (...?)

```
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var circle:Shape = new Shape();
circle.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
circle.graphics.drawCircle(40, 40, 40);

circle.z= 30;

var cont = new MovieClip();
addChild(cont);
cont.addChild(circle);

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkIt);

function checkIt(e:Event){

    trace(circle.hitTestPoint(40,40,true));


    var pos3D= new Vector3D(circle.x,circle.y,circle.z);
    var globalLoc;

    //This line doesn't break hitTestPoint, but it doesn't give the correct
    //global x,y projected coordinates of the circle
    globalLoc=circle.local3DToGlobal(pos3D);
    trace (globalLoc);


    //This line breaks the hitTest but is the only way I can get the correct
    //global x,y projected coordinates of the circle.
    globalLoc=circle.parent.local3DToGlobal(pos3D)
    trace (globalLoc);


    trace(circle.hitTestPoint(40,40,true));
}

stop();
```

EDIT:
Solution I think:

declare pos3D and globalLoc outside the function

and

put the circle in a container.

Sorry, I don't have the fixed code for the example, just implemented it in the full project.

Weird stuff, AS3.